# Verb tenses and types

Tags: verbs, tenses, conditionals

I believe that the verb tenses in:

> She will cry to think that I would leave her

are:

future simple, infinitive, past (of "will").

Am I correct please?

Comment: Mostly. *will cry* is future, *to think* is infinitive, and *would* is the 'past' form--but the form signifies hypotheticality, not past reference

Comment: Tenses are correct, although they don't necessarily agree! "She will cry to think.." ? I'm not sure of the "cry to" construction, though.

Comment: I call "would do/would say"  conditional. But English grammars seem to have no standard term for the would-form, and in conjugation tables this form doesn't occur at all. On the Internet you have trouble to find it. Though the would-forms occur continuously in texts  the English tense system works with present/past/future tense and we have learners here who ask what is "would have been".The problem of English conjugation tables is that the would-forms are somewhere hidden in the box "mood", a box  no learner has seen.

Comment: @rogermue - You'll find *would* and the like under *modal verbs*. They're totally unlike any other verbs, they have defective conjugations, and their uses have been evolving continuously for a thousand years and have been horribly complicated at every point.

Comment: Technically, there is no tense in this sentence. Some grammarians might say that both _will_ and _would_ are present tense -- by default, because they're not past. And some others would say that _will_ is present tense and _would_ is past tense; but there is so little tense about modals -- which always refer to possibility, necessity, obligation, ability, or permission, and never uniquely to time -- that most grammarians would simply rank modal auxiliary verbs with the infinitives that follow them as being uninflectable, and therefore untensed.

Comment: This is a quote that needs a context.  See below.

Comment: 'Technically' is usually used here on ELU to 'prove' 'correctness' by citing a possibly-vaguely-connected construction that hasn't been used for two hundred years, or to try to get away with the etymological fallacy. John Lawler uses it in the correct sense: 'When analysed in accordance with accepted linguistic scholarship'. Of course, 'technically' isn't the way most of this stuff is still taught.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lyric from a Glen Campbell song, "By the Time I Get to Phoenix."  In this line, he says

"And she'll cry just to think I'd really leave her"

He's already left her, and he's thinking about how she will react when she realizes he is gone.  So the first part is the future tense, when she wakes up she will cry, and I think that the "I would really leave her" part is conditional, since in a sense she didn't believe that that would happen.  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The verb tenses in the sentences are future, infinitive future; however, the sentence itself is not a natural English sentence and does not have a clear meaning.

Should it be "She would cry to think that I would leave her"? That would be a natural English sentence, and the tenses would be present conditional, infinitive, present conditional.

The present conditional is formed by the auxiliary *would* which was originally the past tense of *will* but which now functions only as an auxiliary.

Answer (score -1):

If you really wish to re-phrase it correctly, here it is:

"She would cry if she knew (that) I would leave her." (or)
"She will cry at the thought of my leaving her."

(Further to your inquiry as to whether the tenses of the verbs (OP) are corrector not, you may refer to my comment above.)

Comment: There's nothing "incorrect" about the original sentence, really.